# Docker /bin/bash: nodemon: command not found

Tags: node.js, docker, makefile, docker-compose, nodemon

I am trying to mount my working node code from my host into a docker container and run it using nodemon using docker-compose.
But container doesn't seems to be able to find nodemon.
Note: My host machine does not has node or npm installed on it.

Here are the files in the root folder of my project (test). (This is only a rough draft)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM surenderthakran/nodejs:v4
ADD . /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN make install
CMD make run
```

**Makefile**

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
PWD:=$(shell pwd)
export PATH:= $(PWD)/node_modules/.bin:$(PWD)/bin:$(PATH)
DOCKER:=$(shell grep docker /proc/1/cgroup)

install:
    @echo Running make install......
    @npm config set unsafe-perm true
    @npm install

run:
    @echo Running make run......
# Check if we are inside docker container
ifdef DOCKER
    @echo We are dockerized!! :D
    @nodemon index.js
else
    @nodemon index.js
endif

.PHONY: install run
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
app:
    build: .
    command: make run
    volumes:
        - .:/test
    environment:
        NODE_ENV: dev
    ports:
        - "17883:17883"
        - "17884:17884"
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "api",
    "nodejs",
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
```

I build my image using `docker-compose build`. It finishes successfully.
But when I try to run it using `docker-compose up`, I get:

```
Creating test_app_1...
Attaching to test_app_1
app_1 | Running make run......
app_1 | We are dockerized!! :D
app_1 | /bin/bash: nodemon: command not found
app_1 | make: *** [run] Error 127
test_app_1 exited with code 2
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

Can anyone please advice?

**Note:** The Dockerfile for my base image `surenderthakran/nodejs:v4` can be found here: https://github.com/surenderthakran/dockerfile_nodejs/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: If you try interactively, does it work?

Comment: @allprog Yes it works interactively

Comment: Sounds like a PATH issue - try using the full path to nodemon: `/path/to/nodemon`

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel the issue has been resolved. Feel free to suggest a better solution as mine is not very elegant. Thanks

Comment: @allprog the issue has been resolved. Feel free to suggest a better solution as mine is not very elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

The issue has been resolved. The issue boiled down to me not having `node_modules` in the mounted volume.

Basically, while doing `docker-compose build` the image was build correctly with the actual code being *added* to the image and creating the `node_modules` folder by `npm install` in the project root. But with `docker-compose up` the code was being mounted in the project root and it was overriding the earlier added code including the newly created `node_modules` folder.

So as a solution I compromised to install nodejs on my host and do a `npm install` on my host. So when the code my being mounted I still got my `node_modules` folder in my project root because it was also getting mounted from my host.

Not a very elegant solution but since it is a development setup I am ready for the compromise. On production I would be setting up using `docker build` and `docker run` and won't be using `nodemon` anyways.

If anyone can suggest me a better solution I will be greatful.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with npm/node, but I think you could install them to a different url outside of the project root using `npm install -g` and then link to them with `npm link` instead of installing them again locally?  Another alternative might be to install them to a custom path in the container using `npm config set prefix`, then have a symlink in your project directory that points `./node_modules` at that directory. I think that will work with both add and volumes.

Comment: Bullseye solution.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you should use a **preinstall** script in your **package.json**.

So, in the script section, just add script:

```
 "scritpts": {
     "preinstall": "npm i nodemon -g",
     "start": "nodemon app.js",
 }
```

And you should good to go :)

Comment: Maybe you'll need to `RUN npm set unsafe-perm true` before `RUN npm install`.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out how to do this without a Dockerfile, in case that's useful to anyone...

You can run multiple commands in the docker-compose.yml `command` line by using `sh -c`.

```
  my-server:
    image: node:18-alpine
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    command: sh -c "npm install -g nodemon && npm install && npm run dev "
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3100
```

Comment: hey it's perfecto ! Here is my Dockerfile ```FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run",  "dev"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late for an answer. But you could use something called as named volumes to mount your node_modules in the docker volumes space. That way it would hide your bind mount.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the node_modules as a mounted volume in the docker container.

e.g

**docker-compose.yml**

```
app:
build: .
command: make run
volumes:
    - .:/test
    - /test/node_modules
environment:
    NODE_ENV: dev
ports:
    - "17883:17883"
    - "17884:17884"
```